# Android parent of root in xml?

Tags: android

If I had two layouts, layout1.xml and layout2.xml, that are both just empty LinearLayouts, and I set layout1 as an activity's content view:

```
setContentView(R.layout.layout1);
```

Is it possible to add the second layout right under the first?

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
LinearLayout layout2 = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout2);
View parent = // parent of current layout root
parent.addView(layout2);
```

So the hierarchy would look like:

```
<parent>
    <layout1 />
    <layout2 />
</parent>
```

Basically I'm wondering how to get that parent view if it exists.

Comment: You can just use the `<merge />` tag in your xml layout.

Comment: Take a look at [**this**](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.at/2009/03/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-by.html?m=1). It's exactly what you want to do and quite easy when using `<merge />`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to accomplish what you want is to create a third layout (parent.xml) that includes the other two layouts using include tags.  Then setContentView(R.layout.parent);

Have a look here:

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

As an example, consider the following parent layout that pulls in your other two layouts:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include android:id="@+id/layoutOne" layout="@layout/layout1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <include android:id="@+id/layoutTwo" layout="@layout/layout2" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   View parent= getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this :

```
LinearLayout layoutMain = new LinearLayout(this);
    layoutMain.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    setContentView(layoutMain);
    LayoutInflater inflate = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    RelativeLayout layoutFirst = (RelativeLayout) inflate.inflate(R.layout.abc, null);
    RelativeLayout layoutSecond = (RelativeLayout) inflate.inflate(R.layout.xyz, null);
    layoutMain.addView(layoutFirst, 100, 100); // width=100, height=100
    layoutMain.addView(layoutSecond, 100, 100);
```

You can read the documetation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView(android.view.View,%20int,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)).